# Rails: URL/path with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to produce a URL as

```
/swimming/students/get_times/2013-01-01/2013-02-02
```

from this route

```
get_class_swimming_students GET /swimming/students/get_times/:start_date/:end_date(.:format) swimming/students#get_times
```

How do I pass parameters to `get_class_swimming_students_path` ?

Comment: See my answer. It may help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
get_class_swimming_students_path('2013-01-01', '2013-02-02')
```

In Rails, URL parameters are mapped to the router in the precise order in which they are passed. Consider the following:

```
# rake routes
my_route GET    /my_route/:first_param/:second_param/:third_param(.:format)

# my_view.html.erb
<%= link_to('My Route', my_route_path('first_param', 'second_param', 'third_param') %>
#=> <a href="/my_route/first_param/second_param/third_param">My Route</a>
```

Consider also the following case where `foo` and `bar` are static parameters positioned *between* dynamic parameters:

```
# rake routes
my_route GET    /my_route/:first_param/foo/:second_param/bar/:third_param(.:format)

# my_view.html.erb
<%= link_to('My Route', my_route_path('first_param', 'second_param', 'third_param') %>
#=> <a href="/my_route/first_param/foo/second_param/bar/third_param">My Route</a>
```

In the final example, arguments will appear as URL parameters in the *order* in which they were passed, but not necessarily in the same *sequence*.

EDIT:

The following syntax is equivalent to the first snippet. The primary difference is that it accepts arguments as named parameters, rather than in the order they're passed:

```
get_class_swimming_students_path(:start_date => '2013-01-01', :end_date => '2013-02-02')
```

Answer (score 31):

For any path you can pass params like

```
get_class_swimming_students_path(:params1 => value1, :params2 => value2)
```

And In controller you can simply access those passed params as usual

Answer (score 5):

You can also combine named parameters and not named parameters like this:

```
get_class_swimming_students_path('2013-01-01', '2013-02-02', gender: 'M')
```

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use that

```
get_class_swimming_students_path(:start_date => "2013-01-01", :end_date => "2013-02-02")
```

Answer (score 2):

in rails 4, type less with:

```
get_class_swimming_students_path(params1: value1, params2: "value2")
```

where value1 is a method and value2 is a string