# Define url helper in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Haven't needed to use the rails 'url helpers' before, but I am trying to implement something like [Rails: URL/path with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954289/rails-url-path-with-parameters). I did not create any 'resources', but I was under the impression I could prepend the url_helper name in the routes like:

`user_index_path  GET  'users/index',  to: 'users#index'`

but this gives the error:

`undefined method 'GET' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000007ABCDEF> Did you mean? gets gem`

Since I haven't used them much, I'm also confused by the statement I read here, https://blog.arkency.com/all-the-ways-to-generate-routing-paths-in-rails/, saying "Of course instead of _path sometimes you are going to need _url". Am I defining them wrong? Yes, I read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, and saw the bit about '3.16 Direct routes', but this doesn't jive with the examples I've 'seen'.

Comment: Check out the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). If you're trying to put `user_index_path  GET  'users/index',  to: 'users#index'` in your `routes.rb`, then you're going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name routes whatever you want

```
#inside your routes.rb file
get 'users/index', to: 'users#index', as: 'users_index'
```

(note the "get" undercase, what you see on the first link is the output of the command `rake routes`, not the line when you define them)

That route will give you 2 named routes to use: `users_index_path` and `users_index_url` (the latter includes protocol, host, and port).

Comment: Great! Let me work with this for a moment and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit the official Rails routing documentation is quite terse. In short, you can't prepend the path in your **routes.rb** file. Your line should instead read as follows:

```
get 'users/index', to: 'users#index'
```

If you now visit **http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes** or type **rails routes** in your project folder's command prompt, you will see that this gives you the **users_index_path** helper (note the plural). If you wanted this to be the singular - as in your original question - add the "as" option:

```
get 'users/index',  to: 'users#index', as: 'user_index'
```

Then you can use **user_index_path** in your view templates.

Comment: Thanks, that plural/singular thing might have been mixing things up.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the routes wrong.

Try something like this:

`get 'users/index' => "users#index", as: :users`

Then you will get a helper like this: `users_path`

#### But don't do that........

Are you confusing controller actions with routes? Nobody defines a route as 'index'. That's simply assumed.

What you really want will be something like this:

`resources :users, :controller => "users", :only => [:index]`

Then you can use `users_path` to get to a collection of users.

What it does:

- Defines restful routes for the users resource.
- tells you which controller to go to.
- tells you which controller actions are to apply (in this case only one). If you are adding more restful routes, then add them as well. Finally, if you are implementing the whole 9 yards, then simply remove the `:only => [etc]` bit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest and most conventional thing to do would be:

```
get :users, to: 'users#index'
```

which gives you:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)    users#index
```

which you would then use as `users_path`.

If you want to go down the `resources` path (so to speak), then:

```
resources :users, only: [:index]
```

Which also gives you:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)    users#index
```

It is unconventional to have `user_index_path` since `users_path` implies by convention the index action for the `UsersController`.